# Assitance in cms design

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an intermediate asp.net and C# programmer.
I decide to develop a cms that contain below features:

- modules common data, store in one table(contents table)
- modules do not contain any data, only container for displaying data
- information displayed in modules retrieve according to applied filters on modules common data table(contents). filters like(SubjectCode, GroupCode, ContentType, ...)
- modules common settings hold in separate tables(BaseModules and ContentModules)
- all contents contain access level
- feasibility to define skin for modules
- feasibility to commenting and rating contents
- hierarchical page definition
- SEO and Url Rewriting
- theme

I doubt to develop cms myself or use ready cms. Please help me.
I worked for a long time with microsoft portal starter kit.

Image address of database diagram is:

> Blockquote

http://www.4freeimagehost.com/show.php?i=1d3239cad5a2.gif

> Blockquote

Comment: Oh yea i'd love to spend a year in service of your personal laziness!
Or you could learn how to use an existing (many are free) CMS.

Comment: Building a CMS is a great way to learn more advanced ASP.NET topics.  If you're not under a time crunch, I say go for it.  However, if this is for a large project that will have lots of developers maintaining it, do them a favor and find something that's already built and has support.  Otherwise, I don't see a question here.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good free CMS systems out there. I would suggest starting with [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/).

A former employer spent over £200,000 on a system (against my recommendation) on a CMS which was essentially a custom Web User Interface over the top of a free CMS backend. The user interface was very slick, but this just goes to show that you should not try to re-invent the wheel.